Fast API : No module named 'sqlalchemy'
I'm applying the FastAPI to develop an API collection. In VS Code, I've added a virtual environment and a Python interpreter path. sqlalchemy dependency was installed in the venv, but Python was still unable to locate the package. Help is appreciated.
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = 'url'
engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit = False,autoflush=False,bind= engine )

Base = declarative_base()

Error :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/uvicorn/_subprocess.py", line 80, in subprocess_started
    target(sockets=sockets)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 65, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/asyncio/runners.py", line 194, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/asyncio/runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 1517, in uvloop.loop.Loop.run_until_complete
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 69, in serve
    await self._serve(sockets)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 76, in _serve
    config.load()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/uvicorn/config.py", line 434, in load
    self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 22, in import_from_string
    raise exc from None
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 19, in import_from_string
    module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/anoop/testpython/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    from database import Base
  File "/Users/anoop/testpython/database.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy'

Edit :
I followed the procedures below to troubleshoot the error:
checked the interpreter in Vs code verified interpreter in Python:
import sys
print(sys.executable)

Selected the interpreter by giving full path
uninstalled and installed the packages
Restarted the VS code. Now the issue is fixed

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Instead, [edit] your question to include a [mre] of your code and the full error message( starting with "Traceback") as code-formatted text.

How, exactly, did you install sqlalchemy in the venv?

Thanks for the guide. I've updated the question. I installed the package using "pip install sqlalchemy" inside the venv terminal.

Hello, you can also try to download the sqlalchemy package by going into the environment via ./myvenv/Scripts/activate. In the environment, it can be run with the command python database.py.

Based on you stack trace, it seems like your code is not being run from the virtual environment. If it was, I would expect to see the name of the virtual environment in "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py". I would double check and make sure your virtual environment is activated before running you code. You may need to change the Python interpreter to the one created in your virtual environment.
References

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_working-with-python-interpreters
https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#how-venvs-work


Thanks for the reference. But I ensured the venv interpreter is selected and in terminal, venv was selected. But as you said, it should be run in a virtual environment.

I checked "which Python" and other terminal comments in seek of additional details, but all point to venv. Any VS code configuration to be checked?

pip freeze should also show any information about packages installed in the environment you're using. But generally yes, this seems to be the wrong python interpreter compared to which environment you've installed the packages in.
